# Is there a way to build a Web API in the ASP.Net Core ReactJS Template?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I've fiddled with Backend Servers using NodeJS in the past and want to build a Web API for a game. I also want that same Web Server to have a Front-end page (For logging in and changing some data the Web API needs for requests, basically).

I'd like the API to be available via localhost/api/v1/.. and currently have a React Page for the Login stuff ect (using the ASP.Net core React template).

How would I go adding in the Web API part? If I understood correct, the ASP.Net Core React template creates both a react front-end and ASP.Net Core back-end already?

Comment: For Asp.Net Core React template, it already integrates the react and web api. You could check `SampleDataController` for built-in web api controller, you just need to create your own controller with inheriting from `Controller`.